# Problem on relative motion involving wind speed .Finding the real velocity of wind?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, relative-motion

Here is the question

> **For a person running west at 7km/hr wind appears to blow from *north-west* .But when he walks towards west at 3km/hr the wind appears to blow from the north. What is the true velocity and direction of the wind??**

I have tried to solve it and I 've gone through this way 
First I derived two equations

> $V_{W/M}=V_{W/E}-V_{M/E}$
>   $V_{W/M}+V_{M/E}=V_{W/E}$

Therefore the velocity triangle for the first instance will be
[image]

For  the second instance

[image]

here i've got stuck and i dont know how to solve it .There are three unknowns and with 2 velocity triangle . Please refer to my steps and help me to solve it

Note: The velocity triangle in the first instance should be marked a 45deg in between the two vectors because of the north-west direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to go into any serious algebra to solve this problem, just think about the vectors and how they manipulate under changes in your reference frames.

### [Reference Frames](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relmot.html)

Let's say you and your twin are standing at a train station and we see two (VERY LONG) trains coming into the station on parallel tracks at the same time from opposite directions at 5 km/hr, and then they suddenly stop. You saw one of their speeds being 5 km/hr in the WEST direction (lets call that +x), and the other being 5 km/hr in the EAST direction (lets call that the -x direction). We can also say that the second train was travelling -5 km/hr in the WEST direction.

Now let's only you get on the first train, and both trains abruptly continue down the track going 5 km/hr in their respective directions. You have entered a new reference frame, where you are now traveling 5 km/hr in the WEST direction relative to your twin's frame (the rest frame). This also means that your twin looks like he's going 5 km/hr in the EAST direction relative to you.

IF your twin had gotten on the other train and you were looking at him, he would appear to being moving 10 km/hr to the EAST relative to your frame. You would look like you are moving 10 km/hr to the WEST in his reference frame.

The way you can mathematically represent this changing frame is by adding a vector to all your objects that is equal to the change in velocity between your reference frames.

### Conventions

For the purposes of this question the x direction is the direction you are moving, y-direction upwards. The frames I'm using are the 7 3 and rest frames, 7 means that if you are running at 7 km/hr parallel to your vector it would stay the same distance away from you the whole time.

### The Problem

In the 3 frame there is no x component of the wind, it is going at the same relative speed as you (3 km/hr in the x-direction when compared against a rest frame)

Let's go from the 3 frame to the 7 frame to solve for the y component of the wind now.

When you go 4 km/hr faster in the the x-direction the wind in the x-direction appears to go  -4 km/hr. This makes a 45-45-90 triangle, telling you that your y (which doesn't change in any of the 3 frames, is equal in magnitude to -4 km/hr.

So your wind ends up being $<3,-4>$ in the rest frame

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't understand what a frame is. Can you please explain more about that?

Comment: sure, just to make sure, do you have any familiarity with vectors?

Comment: To be honest I'm just a beginner with vectors I've only one month of experience. I've my high school this year. So in first unit of physics i. e mechanics I've studied vector addition and relative motion

Comment: hows that explanation?

Comment: Wonderfully explained.. So the magnitude of the wind would be 5m/s. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, a vote up and answer would make you the person to have me hit over 1k =) .